# What is beam coupling coefficient for linear beam klystron?

Tags: rf, microwave, radar

What does beam coupling coefficient exactly tell? For eg. a voltage gain coefficient tells how much times the input was amplified. So what does beam coupling coefficient tell, like does it tell how much the beam is coupled with something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a linear beam two-cavity klystron acting as a microwave amplifier, the electrons are velocity modulated by the applied input RF signal at the input of the buncher cavity. The beam coupling coefficient describes the degree to which the electrons undergo the process of velocity modulation. It is quite similar to the modulation index which determines the degree to which the carrier is modulated with respect to the message signal.